# Columna' contraseña 'no puede ser nulo'

Tags: php, pdo

hola amigos estoy creando un formulario para registros de usuarios ya que me estoy migrando a PDO y cuando trato de registrar un usuario me da el sihuiente error:

> `Fatal error : Excepción no detectada 'PDOException' con el mensaje 'SQLSTATE [23000]: violación de integridad: 1048 Columna' contraseña 'no puede ser nulo' en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pdo \ registrarse.php: trace 87 Pila: C # 0 : \ xampp \ htdocs \ pdo \ registrarse.php (87): PDOStatement-> execute () {# 1} principal tirado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pdo \ registrarse.php en la línea 87`

el me registraba bien pero le he añadido las siguientes lineas para crear mas seguridad

> `$hash_password= hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);`

y ahora me da ese error anexo cod para ver en que estoy fallando y gracias de ante mano

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


    $user_check = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT user FROM user WHERE user = :user LIMIT 1');
    $user_check->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
    $user_check->execute();

    if($user_check->rowCount() > 0){
        $user_check->closeCursor();
        echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
          <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
             ¡ Ups Aviso: El Nombre de Usuario ya se encuentra Registrado ! 
          </h5>
          </div>";
        header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");
    }else{
        $sql = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO user(id,user,password) VALUES (:id, :user, :hash_password)");
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $sql->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $hash_password= hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
        $sql->bindParam(':hash_password',$_POST['hash_password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();
    }

    if ($sql) {
        echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
        <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
            ¡ Bien Hecho: Cuentra Creada Correctamente !
        </h5>
        </div>";

        header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");

     }

}

?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['hash_password']` no debería ser `$hash_password` ??

Comment: igual me da error, y me dice que la variable no esta definida

Comment: Imposible, la estás declarando justo arriba con `$hash_password= hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);` Revisa si la has escrito correctamente.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: hash_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\registrarse.php on line 87

Comment: Si el problema es una violación de integridad por qué los escribes los datos a insertar (id, usuario y clave) para mirarlos y verificas en la consola SQL cuál es el dato que está incorrecto? No parece ser de la contraseña el problema. ¿Cómo aseguras que el id es único si lo generas desde JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te está diciendo exactamente lo que te está pasando: estás intentando guardar un registro con el campo `contraseña` vacío, el cual es requerido.

**EDICIÓN**

Vale. Me acabo de dar cuenta de que has traducido el mensaje de error. En ese caso, tal y como dice [Muriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38310/columna-contrase%C3%B1a-no-puede-ser-nulo#comment64886_38310), la variable que debes pasar a la consulta debería ser `$hash_password`.

Comment: ahora si registro perfectamente gracias pero tengo dos dudas quisiera agregar esto al codigo    if($_POST['password']!=$_POST['password2']) { 

echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Ups Aviso: Las contraseñas deben coincidir, por favor intentelo de nuevo ! 
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");

 
 }else

Comment: y mi otra duda era cual es mas segura y recomendable usar 'sha256' o 'sha512'

Comment: Yo te diría que intentaras usar la función `password_hash()` en conjunto con `password_verify()`. Ambas usan `bcrypt` por lo que es la forma más segura (ahora mismo) de crear hashes en PHP. [Enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: tendrás un ejemplo nunca he usado eso y perdona tanta molestia